# Aligning div at center doesn't work

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

This is the page: http://trozato.com/

I try to center the whole newsletter(mailchimp) div but it doesnt work. I have put the following code:

```
#mc_embed_signup {
margin: 0 auto;
```

so that it is centered. I want the dimensions to be 400px, also when I try to alter the dimensions of the submit buttons so that they are same, on the browser(chrome tools) with the following code it works but when I put it in the code NOT.

```
#mc_embed_signup input.button {
display: block;
width: 58%;
margin: 0 0 10px 0;
min-width: 90px;
}
```

the  `width: 58%;` should do the work..no?

Comment: Yes, it should work. You can define a percentage as value for a width. It wont solve your problem though. Because you clear it, you should reenter the values for your form. 

So your input and button should get a margin-left and margin-right which should be set to auto

Comment: yeah it should, but it doesnt! the submit  button stays the same. Only on the fly, when I increase the calue of the percentage in chrome tools, it works

Answer (score 2):

Easy: set the margin-left and margin-right of the Input elements to "auto".

Example CSS:

```
#mce-EMAIL
{
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}

#mc-embedded-subscribe
{
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#mc_embed_signup input.button {
display: block;
width: 35%;
margin: 0 auto;
min-width: 90px;
}

#mc_embed_signup input.email {
display: block;
padding: 8px 0;
text-indent: 5px;
width: 58%;
min-width: 130px;
}
```